# c++ callbacks like in java

Tags: c++, function, callback

I wondered if there is a way to implement callbacks in C++ like it's possible in java?
To be more specific: **To define the callback function directly when passing it to another function.**

Something like this:

```
int main(void) {

    ...

    myButton->addOnClickCallback(new myCallback(){

        // do some stuff.
    });

    return 0;
}
```

I didn't find anything similar to this in C++, so I wondered if it's possible.
It would be nice for the sake of convenience :)

Comment: I'd like to know more information on the `myButton->addOnClickCallback` part. Is it implemented by you, or is part of some library? What's the signature?

Comment: It is not "a real code" in that sense. I just used it to give you guys some idea what I mean with "To define the callback function directly when passing it to another function.". So it's just "implemented by myself".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use lambdas from C++11 further on:

```
myButton->addOnClickCallback([](){

   // do some stuff.
});
```

That's the only direct way.

If that's not available, among other solutions, you can pass a pointer to a function, acquired by `&` operator (is not required), not `new`. Secondly, that function must be defined outside `main`:

```
myCallback() {
    // do some stuff.
}

int main (void) {
   myButton->addOnClickCallback(myCallback);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Might want to mention `std::function` for the C++11 solution, since you'd need it to save the callback.

Comment: I think lambdas is what i am looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since lambdas are already covered in another answer, here is another solution (actually, a replica of Java thing):

```
#include <iostream>

struct Base {
  virtual void process() = 0;
};

void want_callback(Base& b) {
  b.process();
}

void foo() {
  struct X : Base {
    void process() {
      std::cout << "Process\n";
    }
  } callback;

  want_callback(callback);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this exactly the way Java does it: a class that needs to interact with another class does so by publishing an interface it expects the collaborator to implement.  The class invokes methods on it's collaborator by calling methods on the callback interface.

I think of lambdas as generalizing function pointers from C than as callbacks.  The standard library uses simple predicates as arguments to its algorithms and lambdas work great with those algorithms.  When the communication back and forth between two collaborating objects becomes more involved, then you must pass in multiple lambdas: one for each interaction that is expected.  Managing this pile of lambdas becomes cumbersome and using an interface starts to win out for comprehension and readability at that point.

For a single interaction that is "fire and forget" and the lifetime of the callback doesn't get messy, then lambdas work great.  With classes implementing interfaces you can more directly control the lifetime of any dependent data and more directly express the nature of the interaction between the two objects.

This approach is exemplified by Sergey's code in his answer.